# Select2 get multiple selected options while editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select2-rails

While editing form, not displaying dropdown value
[edit form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKwPc.png)

```
<%= f.select("project_user_ids",options_for_select(@users, selected: project.project_users.ids), {}, {multiple: true, class: "search_assign_users user-dropdown",id:"search-#{project.id}", :required => true }) %>
```

Comment: hello,
can you please replace "project_user_ids" to project_user_ids. remove that quote and try.
like this 
```<%= f.select(project_user_ids,options_for_select(@users, selected: project.project_users.ids), {}, {multiple: true, class: "search_assign_users user-dropdown",id:"search-#{project.id}", :required => true }) %>```

Comment: Did as you said but not worked

Comment: And I have used select2